# Regular Expression to remove string

Tags: php, mysql, regex, wordpress, preg-replace

Am looking to remove a certain string from my wordpress content. I found that the only way to do it is to run mysql query in database using regex_replace.
I just couldn't figure out how to use the regex to replace this content.,
The string is

```
<ul class="md_wholebook_list"><li class="dZip"><a href="https://example.com/demo/file.zip" title="file.zip" download>Download ZIP</a></li></ul>
```

The string `https://example.com/demo/file.zip` and `file.zip` will be the varying parameters.

This is what I did,

```
<ul class="md_wholebook_list"><li class="dZip"><a href="(.*?)\.zip" title="(.*?)\.zip" download>Download ZIP</a></li></ul>
```

Actually I don't wanna mess with my database, so any wordpress function or php function is much better.If at all only mysql query works, am willing to take the shot.

This is the sql query I ran through my phpmyadmin.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(`post_content`,'<ul class="md_wholebook_list"><li class="dZip"><a href="(.*?)\.zip" title="(.*?)\.zip" download>Download ZIP</a></li></ul>','')
```

Is tat right?

Comment: What's the result you're getting with this regex?

Comment: The `.` before `zip` in `(.*?).zip` needs to be escaped, otherwise it will look for any character preceding `zip`, rather than a literal `.` character

Comment: With my above command, I don't see any result at all.

Comment: @ZaelinGoodman I tried escaping the . character, but I don't see anything getting removed.

Comment: You need a lookbehind in your regexp: `((?<=(href=\"))|(?<=(title=\")))(.*?)\.zip`. It will check if the string you are looking for is following href=" or title=". Use a regExp tool to adjust your regexp's: https://regex101.com/. Also *always* test your regexp's on strings it *must not* match